# Hyper-V Host/OES2 Guest - Guest Time doesnt stay in sync

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, novell

So we've finally migrated from our old Netware environment to a virtualized OES2 system.

Everything is working with the exception of time sync. On boot the time syncs up like normal. But I very quickly GAIN lots of time. About 15 seconds per minute.  The only easy resolution I've found is to run a cron job every 2 minutes to sync the time against an on premises time server. This works fairly well as far as the day to day functionality goes but its a bit aggravating.

On the same host we're running 8 Windows Server VMs that are all working fine with no additional configuration.

Comment: Did you install the Hyper-V Linux Integration Components?

Comment: Sure did Chris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of suggestions (based on the many many OES2 servers I have installed )

1) in boot.msg file under /boot/grub/ on the boot options line before the term showopts add the term "clock=pmtmr" without quotes - reboot server.

2) Use NTP - in the NTP config - choose a decent time source and also remove reference local undisciplined clock - make sure ntp is set to startup (chkconfig ntpd on)

Your time issues will be drastically reduced

Hope this helps

Brett

Comment: Sorry, should have included some of the steps I'd tried. I did both of those, configured NTP the way you're suggesting, NTP will sync once on boot, correctly update the clock, then do nothing ever again.

Comment: Aha - Are you using the Linux Integration Services for Hyper-V?

Comment: See the following link - http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=eee39325-898b-4522-9b4c-f4b5b9b64551

Comment: Yup, got those installed. Synthetic NIC and everything else seems to be working fine. I tried both the original ICs and the latest 2.1 IC.